# How to remove a row from a list of lists if one of the words in it does not contain certain characters in Python?

Tags: python, regex, list, for-loop, row

I have a list of lists that contains lexicons. 
I want to delete lists from the list if they have lexicons that do not contain a pattern of characters such as "(atè|atwa|atif)$". For example :

```
list = [['blablatè', 'blabla'], ['klak'], ['matwa', 'mat'], ['ma', 'mat'], ['ratif']]
```

The expected result would be :

```
[['blablatè', 'blabla'], ['matwa', 'mat'], ['ratif']]
```

I thought I could make it with a loop and re.search(), but it doesn't work. Here's my code :

```
import re
result = [['blablatè', 'blabla'], ['klak'], ['matwa', 'mat'], ['ma', 'mat'], ['ratif']]
rendp = "(atè|atwa|atif)$"
for row in result :
    if re.search(rendp, row) == None : 
        result.remove(row)
joined = '\n'.join(' - '.join(map(str, row)) for row in result)
print(joined)
```

Here's the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alice\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\CréoleDB\CréoleDB\CréoleDB.py", line 65, in <module>
    if re.search(rendp, row) == None :
  File "C:\Users\alice\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I could really use some help. Thanks a lot !

Comment: The error you see is because you are trying to search for the pattern in the inner list. re.search only works when you search for pattern in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `re.compile()`, `regex.search()` and `any()` functions:

```
import re

lists = [['blablaté', 'blabla'], ['klak'], ['matwa', 'mat'], ['ma', 'mat'], ['ratif']]
pat = re.compile(r'(até|atwa|atif)$')  # compiled regular expression object
result = [l for l in lists if any(pat.search(i) for i in l)]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['blablaté', 'blabla'], ['matwa', 'mat'], ['ratif']]
```

---

***P.S.*** Please don't give your variables names as `list`, `dict`, `str` etc. as those are built-in Python data types

Comment: woops, my comment has not been posted... Thanks a lot, it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you are passing a list (`row`) to `re.search`; however, only a string can be used for pattern matching. Try filtering the list using a comprehension:

```
import re
result = [['blablaté', 'blabla'], ['klak'], ['matwa', 'mat'], ['ma', 'mat'], ['ratif']]
rendp = "(até|atwa|atif)$"
final_list = [i for i in result if any(re.findall(rendp, b) for b in i)]
```

Output:

```
[['blablaté', 'blabla'], ['matwa', 'mat'], ['ratif']]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you see is because you are trying to search for the pattern in the inner list. re.search only works when you search for pattern in a string. You can try having a nested loop like this:

```
for word_list in result:
    for word in word_list:
        if re.search(rendp, word) == None:
            word_list.remove(word)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! I'm trying to avoid using nested loops since my script already takes like 20 minutes to run because it's working on a database though, but I'll try that on a simple list of lists.